# Referencing tufte-book sections

Tags: cross-referencing, typography, tufte

I am using the tufte-book class without section numbers which looks very nice.

Is there a visually appealing way to reference chapters and sections? Here is what I am doing at the moment, but I would like to hear some advise from an expert.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{blindtext,cleveref}

\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\textit{\nameref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}\label{ch:chp1}
\blindtext
\section{My Section}\label{sec:sec1}

As defined in \myref{ch:chp1} or \myref{sec:sec1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using name references might be nice for a few occasions, but it extents the text too far, in my point of view.

Comment: You may also consider just citing the relevant page number if the location of the referenced information on the page will be readily apparent to the reader.